# How to initiazlize firebase puse notifications in NativeScript Angular app

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification, nativescript

I am creating an app with nativescript + Angular + Firebase push notifications using this plugin: nativescript-plugin-firebase.
According to their documentation firebase.init should be called OnInit but then after app is reloaded in development i got an error that "Token is already intialized"
Question is how to check if token is already intialized.
I can check by using this code but it is kind of hacky:

```
const initializedToken = await messaging.getCurrentPushToken();

if (initializedToken) {
    return;
}
```

Also i wonder if developemnt app restart = app reopen on real device?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Nativescript but with my Angular knowledge, I can tell you that Place your `firebase.init()` method in the `app.component.ts` file because it is the first component and is always eagerly loaded once the app starts. and then you can use firebase's methods to verify of its initialized or not.

Comment: Thats exactly where i am adding this. But on each change app gets reloaded and i get error saying that firebase was already initialized.

Comment: what kind of change

Comment: on any file save change when app is rebuilt